# Declaring a variable of user-defined type for later initialization

Tags: c++, oop, variable-initialization, boost-process

I want to create a global variable called `process` without assigning anything to it in a first moment. Later on I'll spawn a new process in the operating system, and assign it to that variable.

It can be done in C# like so:

```cs
class TestCS
    {
        // creating a variable
        private System.Diagnostics.Process process;

        private void SomeMethod()
        {
            // assigning a newly spawned process to it
            process = Process.Start("file.exe", "-argument");
            process.WaitForInputIdle();
        }       
    }
```

I wrote the code below to accomplish the same thing with C++. The `process` variable is of type `child` (from [Boost::Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) v0.31). *#includes* are omitted for simplicity.

*Test.hpp*

```
class Test
{
public: 
    void SomeFunction();
private:
    std::string testString; // declaring a test string

    static const std::string program_name;
    static const std::vector<std::string> program_args;
    boost::process::child process;  // attempting to declare a variable of type 'boost::process::child'
};
```

*Test.cpp*

```
void Test::SomeFunction()
{
    testString = "abc"; // I can successfully define the test variable on this line
    std::cout << testString;

    boost::process::context ctxt;

    // the same goes for the next two variables
    const std::string program_name = "startme.exe";
    const std::vector<std::string> program_args = {"/test"};

    // and I want to define the process variable here as well...
    process = boost::process::launch(program_name, program_args, ctxt);
}
```

*Main.cpp*

```
int main()
{
    Test test1;
    test1.SomeFunction();

    cin.get(); // pause
    return 0;
}
```

However, it returns the following error for *Test.cpp*:

> error C2512: 'boost::process::child' : no appropriate default constructor available

How can it be done correctly?

Comment: Everything that you call declarations in your code are actually definitions.

Comment: You need to call the constructor of `boost::process::child` in the `initialization list` of `TestClass::TestClass`

Comment: @AntonSavin can you elaborate?

Comment: why people coming from C# have problems using C++ but not viceversa?

Comment: I guess that's because you program for a framework in C#, which has a huge set of built-in classes (for handling the filesystem, database access, internet comms, etc), and also has typical facilitators of a high-level language (automatic garbage collection, etc). Hence we can say it's an "easier" language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, `'boost::process::child' no appropriate default constructor available`. This means that the `child` object must be constructed with a constructor that takes arguments.

Take the following example class

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(); // This is the _default_ constructor.
    Foo(int i); // This is another constructor.
};

Foo f; // The `Foo();` constructor will be used _by default_.
```

If we change that class to the following:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(int i); // This is the constructor, there is no default constructor declared.
};

Foo f; // This is invalid.
Foo f(1); // This is fine, as it satisfies arguments for `Foo(int i);
```

The reason your `string` is constructed is because it provides a default constructor (which is an empty string), while the `process::child` class does not.

Therefore, you need to initialize you `process::child` object when it's constructed. Since it's a part of `TestClass` (and not a pointer or a reference), it needs to be constructed *when the `TestClass` object is constructed*.

```
Test::Test()
    : process() // Initialize the member here, with whatever args.
{
    SomeFunction();
}
```

Or...

```
class Test
{
    // Make it a pointer.
    boost::process::child* pProcess;
};

Test::Test()
{
    pProcess = new boost::process::child(); // And allocate it whenever you want.
    SomeFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is it that I need to manually initialize `process`, but not the string?

Comment: I've made some changes that should help explain it.

Comment: because the string is implicitly a pointer (as if it was created with new but no need to delete.. oh yeah you have to delete pProcess in destructor.. you have to do finalization in C++ too)

Comment: @DarioOO - Umm no.. The string is _not_ implicitly a pointer. It's a part of `TestClass` and space is allocated for it when the `TestClass` object is created. It just has a _default constructor_ `std::string()` which takes no arguments.

Comment: Great answer, I'm accepting it for my question. I've accomplished my goal using the pointer solution, but would you mind having a look at my additional question (at the end)? I belive that's not possible, just want to be sure.

Comment: If you want to make it reference another `process`, declare it like so: `boost::process::child& process`. Then initialize it in the initializer list `TestClass::TestClass(const boost::process::child& otherProcess) : process(otherProcess) {}`